# docker-compose.yml invalidate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hello I have a default config for regular operation.
Now i want to overwrite things from the first yml with a 2nd yml.
To be precise, the location of a volume.

docker-compose.yml:

```
...
volumes:
  database:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /opt/data/database/
      o: bind
```

but i want to use the default location (/var/libs/docker/volumes/project_database/_data) in case of development.

is there a priority of the options according to the order in which they are called?
-f a.yml -f b.yml
b.yml will override a.yml or something like this?

to comment out the lines in docker-compose.yml is not the way i want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Extend services in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) in the Docker documentation states:

> To use multiple override files, or an override file with a different name, you can use the `-f` option to specify the list of files. Compose merges files in the order they’re specified on the command line.

So in your example (`docker -f a.yml -f b.yml ...`) the definitions in the later file will augment the definitions in the earlier file.  Compose by default knows about a `docker-compose.override.yml` file which will augment the default `docker-compose.yml` file in this way, without explicit `-f` options.

The same page has a list of rules for [Adding and overriding configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration).  If something is a logical list (like `expose`), values from the later file are appended; if a logical map (like `environment`), values from the later file replace values from the earlier file; and if a logical scalar value (like `image`), values from the later file are used.

Top-level `volumes:` aren't specifically discussed, but I would expect them to act the way you want them to from this documentation.  If both files provide a definition for a named volume, the definition in the later file takes precedence, but it's valid for a volume to be declared in only one or the other.

(This is borne out in the Compose Python code.  [`compose.config.load()`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/7f7370b811004583e12593a61fc265e8705f359c/compose/config/config.py#L412) takes a configuration including a list of file names and returns the merged dictionary-format configuration.  For all of the top-level keys except `services:` it defers to a generic [`load_mapping()`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/7f7370b811004583e12593a61fc265e8705f359c/compose/config/config.py#L454); beyond some specific object keys, this just performs a shallow merge where the complete definition from the later file replaces definitions from the earlier file.  Of note this means you must supply all of the per-volume options in the override file.)